# Call a Shipping field from front end to backend Magento 2 Layout processor

Tags: magento2, layout, orders, shipping

I have added a custom delivery date option in shipping method on front end using layout processor and it is showing and working fine. Is there any way to merge or call the same method in backend order creation page. i.e same layout processor for admin order page to select the delivery date.

> **di.xml**

```
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
    <plugin name="my_checkout_layout_processor_add_delivery_block"
            type="Vendoor\Module\Plugin\Checkout\Block\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

> **LayoutProcessor.php**

```
    <?php
namespace Vendoor\Module\Plugin\Checkout\Block;


class LayoutProcessor
{


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array $jsLayout
    ) {

        $requiredDeliveryDate =  false;
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shippingAdditional'] = [
            'component' => 'uiComponent',
            'displayArea' => 'shippingAdditional',
            'children' => [
                'delivery_date' => [
                    'component' => 'Vendoor_module/js/view/delivery-date-block',
                    'displayArea' => 'delivery-date-block',
                    'deps' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'dataScopePrefix' => 'delivery_date',
                    'children' => [
                        'form-fields' => [
                            'component' => 'uiComponent',
                            'displayArea' => 'delivery-date-block',
                            'children' => [
                                'delivery_date' => [
                                    'component' => 'Vendoor_module/js/view/delivery-date',
                                    'config' => [
                                        'customScope' => 'delivery_date',
                                        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                                        'elementTmpl' => 'Vendoor_module/fields/delivery-date',
                                        'options' => [],
                                        'id' => 'delivery_date',
                                        'data-bind' => ['datetimepicker' => true]
                                    ],
                                    'dataScope' => 'delivery_date.delivery_date',
                                    'label' => 'Delivery Date',
                                    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                                    'visible' => true,
                                    'validation' => [
                                        'required-entry' => $requiredDeliveryDate
                                    ],
                                    'sortOrder' => 10,
                                    'id' => 'delivery_date'
                                ]
                            ],
                        ],
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```